# Can we validate date in Amazon Lex?

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a Hotel Management lex bot that makes a reservation for hotel rooms. I am using slots (**Check-in Date** and **Check-out Date**). I am using built-in slot that is Amazon.Date.

**Problem**

I want to restrict customers at this stage so that customers can only enter date that matches with the current date or after the current date. Currently, these slots are accepting all dates including previous dates.

*How I can validate these slots? (Can we solve our problem with RegEx while using Amazon.Alphanumeric type)*

*What are the possible solutions?*

*Should we handle this in Lambda? (If yes, kindly describe how I can get the Elicitation value of a slot in Lambda (Python)).*

*What would you prefer me to resolve or achieve this?*

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Amazon LEx in a web site?  If so and assuming you are coding the solution using JavaScript, determine valid dates using JS. No need to call a Lambda function for basic date calculations

Comment: I am just creating a bot, will integrate it with AWS Connect, and then I will create a chat widget on my site. But I am already using Lambda function in Lex Bot.

Comment: Hi there. To answer, yes, you should be using Lamba functions to perform verification of user input. A lot of your concerns have already been dealt with in the AWS Lex sample bots. 

In the Lex V2 console, select the `Start with an example` option and select the `BookTrip` demo from the drop down.

This will deploy a fully-functional Lex bot complete with supporting Lambdas that demonstrate how to use Lambda's to validate user input, direct bot behaviour and provide fulfillment of intents. 

Feel free to ask more questions once the demo has given you some direction.

Comment: Is there any other solution, other than lambda?

Comment: No. AWS have enabled native Lambda integration and provided the supporting framework to enable developers to build rich, customized experienced through the use of Lambda functions.